# Starting an investment portfolio

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, isa

I am looking to start an investment portfolio with around £1000 of my savings going into the stock market and was wondering how I would go about doing this.

I would like to spread this money across a few moderate to high risk investments with the hope of high returns, I also will be placing around £4000 into an ISA to maximise savings.

My current financial situation is fairly stable, I don't have debt other than a student loan but I also don't own property. I will be setting up a pension plan within a couple of months and my employer will also contribute to that.

My aim is to be able to save using the ISA for the deposit on a house, and if needed have investments I can sell off to contribute to this.

My main questions are:

1. Is this amount an adequate starting amount to begin investing with?
2. Which services should I use to start buying shares? (Currently my bank offers this service but I'm willing to use other sources)
3. I would like to regularly increase the amount invested in shares. Is it worth doing this in say £200 increments?
4. When buying shares should I focus on say two or three companies, or diversify more?

But any other advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hi!  I removed the part of your question requesting investing book recommendations.  You can find some at these other questions: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-is-your-favorite-book-on-the-topic-of-investing and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5949/totally-new-to-finance-economy-where-should-i-start and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/i-want-to-be-rich-when-i-am-middle-aged-what-books-should-i-read-to-get-me-start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this amount an adequate starting amount to begin investing with?

Yes. You can open an account at a brokerage with this amount.

I'm not sure I would invest in individual stocks at this point.

> Which services should I use to start buying shares? (Currently my bank offers this service but I'm willing to use other sources)

I can't make UK-specific recommendations, but I'd compare your bank's fees to those of a discount broker -- as well as the variety and level of service available.

> I would like to regularly increase the amount invested in shares. Is it worth doing this in say £200 increments?

Take a look at the fees associated with each investment. Divide the fee by the increment to see what percent you'll lose to fees/commissions. Keep in mind that you have to gain more than that percentage to start earning a positive return on your investment.

If you have access to fee-free automatic mutual fund investments, and you can commit to the £200 amount on a regular basis going forward, then this can be a completely free way of making these incremental investments.

See also [this answer on dollar cost averaging](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/finding-a-brokerage-for-dollar-cost-averaging/7079#7079), and my comment on the other answer on that question for how fees impact returns.

> When buying shares should I focus on say two or three companies, or diversify more?

I would diversify into two or three different *index funds*. Read up on [asset allocation](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/asset-allocation). For example, you might invest 1/3 of your balance into S&P 500 index fund, bond index fund, and MSCI EAFE index fund (but that's just a rough example, and not necessarily good for *you*). I highly recommend "The Intelligent Asset Allocator" by William Bernstein for excellent info on diversification and asset allocation.